# How to configure QuickCheck with cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal, quickcheck

I'm learning to build a Haskell package. One thing I'm stuck with is running tests with QuickCheck.

Specifically, how can I configure the number of trials to run?

Here is my test file (`Test.hs`) with a dummy test:

```hs
module Main where

import System.Exit (exitFailure)
import Test.QuickCheck

prop_PermInvariant xs = length xs == length (reverse xs)
  where types = xs :: [Int]

main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck prop_PermInvariant
```

And here is my `.cabal` file:

```
Test-Suite tests
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is: Test.hs
  default-language: Haskell2010
  build-depends:
    base ^>= 4.14.3.0,
    QuickCheck > 2.14,
  hs-source-dirs: tests
```

After building the package, I can do `cabal test`, which will run 100 trials on my dummy test. But how to change that to run 10000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation for `quickCheck`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:quickCheck) says "To run more tests, use [`withMaxSuccess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:withMaxSuccess)." In your case specifically, you'd change `main = quickCheck prop_PermInvariant` to `main = quickCheck (withMaxSuccess 10000 prop_PermInvariant)`. There's no reason to configure anything in Cabal at all.